# How to search on unicode characters with alphabets?

Tags: ios, search, unicode, nsstring, ascii

I want to implement search on some strings with unicode character but user will enter alphabets. Based on that alphabets, search should be apply on all data (including unicode). Example: if user search by keyword **"cre"**,it should return **"crème"**. In sort **"è"** can be searched by **"e"**. Same for **"A"-"À"** and so on.

I tried

```
NSString* finish = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

but it doesn't work. Any other solution please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I surfed and I found something useful exactly what I need. I want to answer my question so if anybody stuck with the same problem like me, he can get solution asap. It implies search on all unicode/alphabetic characters.

answer is when you search, set your search options as given below.

```
NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSWidthInsensitiveSearch
```

My code :

**

```
NSRange nameRange = [stringtosearch rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSWidthInsensitiveSearch];
if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
         // do what you want to do when its found.
```

**